# Powershell delete all folders except one

Tags: powershell

I tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse Select Name | Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\temp\one*'} | sort length -Descending | Remove-Item -force
```

but it doesn't work

> Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Name'

What's wrong

Comment: Your code isn't valid Powershell. Presumably `Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse Select Name` should be `Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse | Select Name`, but the rest of your code is very unclear and is nowhere near "deleting all folders except one". For example, why are you sorting? Your code deletes files as well as folders. Is that intentional? Your code might delete files from the current folder. Is that intentional? Your Where expression is going to be always true. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing a **|**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\temp\one*'} | Remove-Item -force
```

Comment: Ah year thanks, it's such a long time I didn't touch Powershell I forgot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `-Exclude` (And why sort when deleting files?)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\temp' -Recurse -Exclude 'C:\temp\one*' | Remove-Item -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function below:

```
Function Delete-Except
{
$path = ""
$exceptions = @(
#Enter files/folders to omit#
)
try:
Get-ChildItem $source -Exclude $exceptions| Remove-Item $_ -Force -Recurse
catch:
Write-Host "Delete operation failed." - Foregroundcolor Red
Pause
}
```